# Spinnaker "Create Application" menu doesn't load

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I'm quite new to the Spinnaker and have to ask for some help I guess. Does anyone knows why it could be that I can't create any Application and just keep seeing this screen.
My installation is through Halyard 1.5.0 and Ubuntu 14.04.
We don't use any cloud provider but I did configure Docker and Kubernetes part

And here is the error I see in the /var/log/spinnaker/echo/echo.log:

```
2017-11-16 13:52:29.901  INFO 13877 --- [ofit-/pipelines] c.n.s.echo.services.Front50Service       : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:127)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:739)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:87)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:724)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:578)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:287)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.invoke(RestAdapter.java:265)
at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at retrofit.Platform$Base$2$1.run(Platform.java:94)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:204)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
... 24 more

2017-11-16 13:52:29.901  INFO 13877 --- [ofit-/pipelines] c.n.s.echo.services.Front50Service       : ---- END ERROR
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be using `redis` as the persistent storage type(I ran into the same issue).

If this is the case, persistent storage using redis doesn't seem to be working properly out-of-the-box, and it is not supported. I would try using an S3 target, if available.

[More info here on support for redis](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/storage/redis/)

To configure S3 using Halyard, use the following commands:

```
echo <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY> | hal config storage s3 edit --access-key-id <ACCESS_KEY_ID> --endpoint <S3_ENDPOINT> --bucket <BUCKET_NAME> --root-folder spinnaker --secret-access-key
hal config storage edit --type s3
hal deploy apply
```

Answer (score 1):

@grizzthedj

thanks again for recommendations. It doesn't seem, however, solved the issue. I wonder if it has something to do with my Docker Registry or Kubernetes.
Here is what I have in my .hal/config:

```
dockerRegistry:
  enabled: true
  accounts:
  - name: <hidden-name>
    requiredGroupMembership: []
    address: https://docker-registry.<hidden-name>.net/
    cacheIntervalSeconds: 30
    repositories:
    - hellopod
    - demoapp
  primaryAccount: <hidden-name>

kubernetes:
  enabled: true
  accounts:
  - name: <username>
    requiredGroupMembership: []
    dockerRegistries:
    - accountName: <hidden-name>
      namespaces: []
    context: sre-os1-dev
    namespaces:
    - spinnaker
    omitNamespaces: []
    kubeconfigFile: /home/<username>/.kube/config
```

Comment: Based on the error, your issue is with Front50, which is the service for persisting the spinnaker data. What kind of errors are you seeing in the Front50 log?  `/var/log/spinnaker/front50/front50.log`

Answer (score 0):

@grizzthedj,
Here is what I've found inside front50.log (I wiped out ID's of course for security reasons)
You may be right.

```
2017-11-20 12:40:29.151  INFO 682 --- [0.0-8080-exec-1] com.amazonaws.latency                  : ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSErrorCode=[NoSuchKey], StatusCode=[404], ServiceEndpoint=[https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com], Exception=[com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: ...; S3 Extended Request ID: ...), S3 Extended Request ID: ...], RequestType=[GetObjectRequest], AWSRequestID=[...], HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, RetryCapacityConsumed=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=1, RequestCount=1, Exception=1, HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, ClientExecuteTime=[39.634], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.072], HttpRequestTime=[39.213], RequestSigningTime=[0.067], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.001, 0.0], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[39.059],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on kubernetes/aws, when I opened up the chrome dev console I  was getting lots of 404 errors trying to connect to localhost:8084, I had to reconfigure the deck and gate baseurls.  This is what I did using halyard:

```
hal config security ui edit --override-base-url http://<deck-loadbalancer-dns-entry>:9000
hal config security api edit --override-base-url http://<gate-loadbalancer-dns-entry>:8084
```

i did `hal deploy apply` and when it came back I noticed the developer console was throwing cors errors so I had to do the following.

```
echo "host: 0.0.0.0" | tee \ ~/.hal/default/service-settings/gate.yml \ ~/.hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml
```

You may note the lack of TLS and cors config, this is a test system so make better choices in production :)